# Solve $x^2 - 3x - 5 \equiv 0 \pmod{343}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

I'm trying to solve $$x^2 - 3x - 5 \equiv 0 \pmod{343}$$

I've tried to look up similar problems on the Internet [[1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/26339/237591)] but most of them use Hensel's Lemma which I cannot use as it wasn't introduced by my professor.

The problem is that I cannot transform $x^2 - 3x - 5$ into any familiar form I'd be able to solve. Plus, I've found that $x\in\{1,2\}$ for $x^2 - 3x - 5 \equiv 0 \pmod{7}$. How can I approach this congruence?

Comment: Try completing the square!

Comment: @JavaMan Good hint! I forgot about it.

Comment: So, in the first case $x \equiv 1\pmod{7}$, write $x = 1+7a$, so then $343 \mid (49a^2 + 14a + 1) - (3 + 21a) - 5 = 49a^2 - 7a - 7$.  Thus $49 \mid 7a^2 - a - 1$ so $7 \mid -a-1$ which tells you $a \equiv 6\pmod{7}$, and therefore $x \equiv 43 \pmod{49}$.  Then, similarly, you can write $x = 43 + 49b$ and substitute to figure out what $x$ is congruent to $\pmod{343}$.

Comment: Then repeat for the case $x \equiv 2\pmod{7}$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler I got it. Thank you.

Comment: See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2287021/236182) for how to solve quadratic congruences in general. In this case, though, we get $(2x-3)^2\equiv 29\pmod{7^3}$, which doesn't seem to make the problem easier. $29$ is a quadratic residue mod $7^3$.